# zend 2 view rendering template with same name from a different module

Tags: view, zend-framework2, rendering, code-duplication

I'm working with reusable modules in Zend2 and I have a little problem which concerns code duplication.

I have an User module, which has i.e an HTML template register (template path: user/user/register).
It contains some basic HTML but in one of my projects, I need to embed this template with a < div > for CSS stylization (the rest of the HTML page doesn't change).

After the User module, I load my Application module where I can overwrite the user/user/register template and put new code but I'm unable to render the original user/user/register template through it.

Example of code in Application module -> user/user/register:

```
<div><?=$this->render('user/user/register')?></div>
```

This causes an endless loop and I don't want to copy/paste all the HTML from my user/user/register template in User module.

Anyone can help me ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to achieve won't work. You can not have two templates with identical names. The Module that loads the key the latest will always have priority.

You have to understand that templates are just a key inside a big array.

```
'view_manager' => array(
    'template_map' => array(
        'layout/layout' => 'my\layout.phtml'
    )
)
```

So if you have two modules providing this configuration, it doesn't change the fact that both use the key `layout/layout`. Therefore whatever Module loads later, wins.

**TL/DR** You can only overwrite templates, not extend them. In your case you have to create a separate template.

Comment: I understand the principle, what I was just asking is a way to not duplicate code between 2 templates which one IS EXACTLY the content of the second plus some html code around. As I don't find a solution for, I just duplicated the template code but it creates a lot of code debts for further updates of the template.

Is there a way to reach a template path in a specific module ? Like I want to render user/user/register in the User module from the template user/user/register in Application module ?

Comment: you should NOT have identical template names, that's the whole idea. Templates should be namespaced just like classes. name ur 2nd module "user2/user/register" and then render a partial "user/user/register" and you're good

Comment: Ok, I get it.
My Application module has to rewrite the route user/register and tells it to use "ApplicationUser" as controller (instead of User controller) then my "ApplicationUser" controller -> registerAction forwards the request to my User module (registerAction) and returns the result. The view called is now application/application-user/register and this renders a partial " user/user/register" template.

Thx a lot.